# Why must $\left(F^{2 \times 2}, +\right)$ be abelian group?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to determine the reason why must $\left(F^{2 \times 2}, +\right)$ be Abelian group. I know it is a group but I don't know why it has to be Abelian. Please explain why it is a must. $\left(F^{2 \times 2}\right)$ is not defined, it covers all 2x2 matrices. So, I guess my question is, how is $\left(F^{2 \times 2}, +\right)$ communitive.

Comment: Can you define F^2x2?

Comment: Is this the set of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field $F$?  Then you can use the definition of  addition of matrices to show that addition is commutative.